# cffeed causing errors

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, cffeed

Our web admins applied some hotfixes (don't know which ones) over the weekend and it seems to have killed `<cffeed>`. The error we get is below. We have the `<cffeed>` tag inside of a `<cftry>` but it still produces the error. Any thoughts on what would be causing the error or or how to circumvent without rewriting all our code?

```
ROOT CAUSE: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class coldfusion.syndication.FeedDateParser
    at coldfusion.tagext.io.FeedTag.<init>(FeedTag.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor555.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at coldfusion.runtime.NeoPageContext$TagSet.getTagHandlerInstance(NeoPageContext.java:2284)
    at coldfusion.runtime.NeoPageContext.getTagHandlerInstance(NeoPageContext.java:2192)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._initTag(CfJspPage.java:1789)
    at cfindex2ecfm2002820310.runPage(D:\WEB\ROOT\itap\index.cfm:156)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:196)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:483)
    at coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.invoke(CfincludeFilter.java:65)
    at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:288)
    at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48)
    at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
    at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:86)
    at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:70)
    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserDebugFilter.invoke(BrowserDebugFilter.java:74)
    at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46)
    at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
    at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:198)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86)
    at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)
    at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
    at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
    at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
    at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
```

Comment: Have you tried to test cffed separately from your app? If it fails with the plain standalone .cfm too, it looks like a bug that should be posted to the Adobe.

Comment: Yes it errors out no matter what it is with. This did not happen before the hot fixes were applied.

Comment: uninstall hotfix, test again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this is a sandbox issue. We have security sandboxing turned on. When the hot fixes were put into place, the path to /WEB-INF/cfusion/lib/ needed to be added to the sandbox. So far the only thing we have found that this affects is cffeed. Also, ColdFusion had to be restarted when the changes were made.